When NUT runs upssched-cmd it does not set environment variables for LOGNAME and HOME
I set up NUT on an Ubuntu system and in my upssched-cmd I want to run some scripts to shut down equipment. I have upsmon.conf set to run the upssched-cmd as a user, currently root but I want to be able to change that if needed.
What I have found is that when upssched-cmd runs, some of the normal user related environment variables aren't set. I can't use $HOME to retrieve or save files or use $LOGNAME for logging what happened if something went wrong.
Is there a reason why upssched-cmd would not set those? is it because it's not an interactive process running in a terminal and those are only used in terminal sessions?
Given that $HOME is not set, is there a different way to retrieve the current user's home directory in a case like this?
When upssched-cmd is called, this is the env:
MEMORY_PRESSURE_WRITE=c29tZSAyMDAwMDAgMjAwMDAwMAA=
PIDFILE=/run/nut/upsmon.pid
PWD=/
SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID=1331
NOTIFYTYPE=ONBATT
LANG=C.UTF-8
MEMORY_PRESSURE_WATCH=/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/nut-monitor.service/memory.pressure
MODE=netserver
INVOCATION_ID=f025fd10826a4bac950193c70322fba0
USER=root
SHLVL=0
UPSNAME=ophiuchia@localhost
JOURNAL_STREAM=8:16568
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin
_=/usr/bin/env


What environment variables do get set? env | sort will show.
What prevents you from picking a userid and using:
#!/bin/bash
export USER="nut"
export LOGNAME="$USER"
export HOME="$(getent passwd $USER  | cut -d: -f6)"
export UID="$(getent passwd $USER  | cut -d: -f3)"
export GID="$(getent passwd $USER  | cut -d: -f4)"

at the beginning of yours script?

I was not familiar with getent. When I run those commands I get an error saying Unknown database: <my username>. Too bad because it seems like those would definitely solve the problem for me.

The arguments to getent should be the other way around: getent passwd $USER.

@meih Thanks, fixed. I should have RTFM.

@SteveHiner I had the getent params reversed. Fixed now.

Thank you @meuh and @waltinator, I should have RTFM myself. Turns out I could have tldr to get it too.
